# Removing rows in a pandas dataframe after groupby based on number of elements in the group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm stuck trying to figure out the following: Given a pandas dataframe, I would like to group by by one of the columns, remove the first row in each group if the group has less than `n` rows, but remove the first and last row in each group if the group has `n` or more rows. Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by applying conditional logic like this :

```
n = 3 # or any other desired value for n
df.groupby('column_to_group_by').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1:-1] if len(x) >= n else x.iloc[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use boolean masks:

```
n = 3

# Conditions
first = df['col1'].ne(df['col1'].shift())
last = first.shift(-1, fill_value=True)
greater = df.groupby('col1').transform('size').gt(n)

# reverse the mask with '~' to keep rows with loc[] instead of using drop()
out = df.loc[~(first | (last & greater))]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   col1  col2
1     A     1
2     A     2
3     A     3
4     A     4
7     B     1
8     B     2
9     B     3
12    C     1
13    C     2
15    D     1

>>> df.join(pd.concat([first, last, greater], keys=['first', 'last', 'greater'], axis=1))
   col1  col2  first   last  greater
0     A     0   True  False     True  # drop (first)
1     A     1  False  False     True
2     A     2  False  False     True
3     A     3  False  False     True
4     A     4  False  False     True
5     A     5  False   True     True  # drop (last & greater)
6     B     0   True  False     True  # drop (first)
7     B     1  False  False     True
8     B     2  False  False     True
9     B     3  False  False     True
10    B     4  False   True     True  # drop (last & greater)
11    C     0   True  False    False  # drop (first)
12    C     1  False  False    False
13    C     2  False   True    False
14    D     0   True  False    False  # drop(first)
15    D     1  False   True    False
```